# prevent double booking in python (schedule checker)

Tags: python

This part of code is supposed to make sure we're not booking events for employees that are already booked in a specified time frame.

If Marc is booked from 9AM to 11AM. IT shouldnt be possible to book for Marc from 9AM to 10AM, or 7AM to 9AM, etc.

This is the conditions where:

1. `(currentStart, CurrentEnd)` = Start and End of new appointment.
2. `event['start']['dateTime']` and `event['end']['dateTime']` = Start and end of the appointment already registered in callendar.

These are the conditions were a second appointment shouldn't be allowed:

```
if str2datetime(currentStart) >= str2datetime(event['start']['dateTime'].split('+')[0]) and str2datetime(currentEnd) <= str2datetime(event['end']['dateTime'].split('+')[0]):
    event_done = False
    break

elif str2datetime(currentStart) <= str2datetime(event['start']['dateTime'].split('+')[0]) and str2datetime(currentEnd) <= str2datetime(event['end']['dateTime'].split('+')[0]):
    event_done = False
    break

elif str2datetime(currentStart) >= str2datetime(event['start']['dateTime'].split('+')[0]) and str2datetime(currentEnd) > str2datetime(event['end']['dateTime'].split('+')[0]):
    event_done = False
    break
```

Comment: What's your question? Please [edit] to clarify. BTW welcome to SO! Check out the [tour] if you haven't already, and [ask] if you want advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a fairly simple condition to check if two datetime ranges overlap. Given 2 datetime ranges `a` and `b` - if the start of `a` is before the end of `b` and the end of `a` is after the start of `b` then they overlap

```
a.start < b.end and a.end > b.start
```